# Why does my instance not show up in SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

I downloaded Management Studio from that site and am using VS12 but the studio doesn't display the database I created in my MVC application in its Object Explorer pane. Is this an incompatibility issue or just a mistake in the server reference for the engine to connect to ?

Comment: Are you *connecting* to the right instance? For example, is it the *default* instance, or a *named* instance? You might need to connect to `./EXPRESS`, for example (`.` is the default instance on the local machine; `./FOO` is an instance called `FOO` on the local machine, etc)

Comment: Did you connect to it?  If not, google for instructions.

Comment: well, thank you, it connects to a different storage of DBs. I need to view my DBs created in VS12 but only DBs created in VS10 are up on the OE pane

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio will not show instances of SQL Express in the database explorer pane.